# How does the durability of an Anvil decrease?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, anvils have durability. They go from normal to cracked, and eventually become nothing.

How does an anvil break? I know that the durability can decrease if it falls from a height, but will simply using the anvil break it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, using the anvil can damage and eventually break it.

Each use has a 12% chance of damaging the anvil. Damaging the anvil changes it to slightly damaged the first time, very damaged the second time and breaks it the third time (though the item is still upgraded). This means an anvil will last, on average, 25 uses.

Comment: Do note that this is on average: it is possible that your anvil lasts 100 or more uses, or breaks after three.